# Angular dynamic attribute binding via function

Tags: angular, data-binding

I want to bind a range of functions to a range of buttons' `[disabled]` attribute. I have a range of buttons and a range of functions:

```
<mat-button-toggle 
  *ngFor="let button of buttons" 
  [disabled]="this['auth' + button.authLevel + '()']">
  {{button.displayName}}      
</mat-button-toggle>


auth100(){
    let var = complicatedStuff();
    return var;
}
auth200(){
    return false;
}
```

(and yes, `buttons` is a JSON like `[{authLevel: '100', displayName: 'Button Name'}, ...]` etc.)

And this does not seem to work. If I try it with variables instead of functions, e.g. `auth100 = false;` and `"this['auth' + button.authLevel]"`, it does work, but I want to be able to bind it to a function. Currently I'm thinking I should just do `auth100var = auth100();` and just bind the `auth100var` variable instead a function, but I feel like you should be able to bind a function and that would be the proper way to do it, but how?

Comment: why do not you think in something like `[disabled]="function(button.authLevel)"` ? I can imagine what kind of validation you need to disable buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the place where you put the parentheses for calling the function. They are not part of the key by which you access the property.

```
  [disabled]="this['auth' + button.authLevel]()">
```

[See live demo (stackblitz)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxtdud)

Comment: This does not seem to recognize it as a function, it binds as `ng-reflect-disabled="auth100() {return tru"` (yes, cut off like that).

Comment: Don't forget about the parentheses at the end. See [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxtdud)